# Python: How to write a function to print 'height' lines, each with 'sym' repeated 'length' times?

Tags: python

Below is my work. I did the printline function before, and this question required to call the function printline above for printing each line. I try to print 3 lines, each line has 4 symbols, but I only can get 2 lines, each line comes with 12 symbols. Can someone help me correct my code?

```
def printline(num,sym):
    for i in range(num):
        a = (num*sym)
    return a
a = printline(5,'*')
print(a)

def printrectangle(num,height,sym):
    for i in range(height):
        a = printline(num,sym)*height
        print(a)
        return a
c = printrectangle(3,4,'*')
print(c)
```

Comment: I see a few issues here. In your `printlines` you're only ever going to return `num*sym` since you reassign `a` in the last iteration, so the loop isn't doing anything. In `printrectangle` you return inside the loop, which means it will end the function on the first iteration. The reason you get two lines instead of one is that you print it in the function, then print the return value.You get 12 because you multiply the 3 from the `printline` with the height, 4

Comment: @user12889057 Please show the example of the output you want. Are you sure you are not swapping num and height values?

Comment: @pk786 Print 3 lines, each line has 4 symbols.

Comment: @G.Anderson I deleted the loop for the printlines. But still cannot fix the printrectangle

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1. Your printline function works, but overcomplicates the problem.

In other programming languages, in order to repeat the same string multiple times it is common to create a loop of the form:

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
   s += sym;
return s;
```

Since this is equivalent to just concatenating the same string `num` times, in python there is a simpler way to do this:

```
s = sym*num
```

Your solution works because you are overwriting the value in the variable `a` for `num` times before returning it.

2. You misinterpreted your testcase.

You said `printrectangle(3, 4, '*')` should print 3 lines with 4 symbols. But as you wrote it, the first variable `num=3`, and the second variable `height=4`.
The output here is in fact:

```
***
***
***
***
```

Your code does not currently do that, but let's not get ahead of ourselves.

3. Indentation error

The return statement in the `printrectangle` function is inside the loop. This means that during the first iteration of the loop, the function will return a value.
Easy fix, just backspace until the indentation of the return lines up with that of the loop.

4. Actually solving the problem.

From part 1, I introduced here that in python to concatenate the same string multiple times you may simply multiply the string by the number of times you want it to show up.

Here we want the string `printline(num, sym)` to show up `height` times with an enter key after each time.

The enter key sends the command of `\n`. In other words, a string such as `'a\nb'` is printed as:

```
a
b
```

For our purposes, we can concatenate the string `printline(num, sym)` with `\n` first, and then multiply the resulting string by `height` to get the result of `printrectangle(num, height, sym)`

```
def printrectangle(num, height, sym):
    a = (printline(num, sym)+'\n')*height
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this code will give you what you are looking for, I still doubt by mistake you swapped **num** and **height** values in the call **printrectangle(3,4,'*')** itself

```
def printline(h,sym):
    a = h*sym # removed unnessary loop
    return a

def printrectangle(num,height,sym):
    for i in range(num): # swap height with num in your code
        a = printline(height,sym) #swap num with height in your code
        yield a

for row in printrectangle(3,4,'*'):
    print(row)
```